# Single Sign On through Citrix

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, iis-7, citrix, single-sign-on

I have a webserver running Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7. The server is a member of the domain "mydomain.com". What I am trying to achieve is a SSO connection between the AD users and the web server. The problem is that users must connect via Citrix to join the same domain ("mydomain.com"). It is not I who controls the AD accounts, and Server Admin makes it very difficult for me to find out how the structure looks like.

What I'm wondering is: Is it possible to achieve SSO with this solution? At the moment the $ _SERVER ['REMOTE_USER'] and $ _SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] is empty. :\

I've installed a similar solution a few weeks ago. Except everything was running locally on the same network.

**IIS 7 Server settings:**

Anonymous Authentication: Enabled

Windows Authentication: Enabled

Comment: When I disable "Anonymous Authentication" I can log on via the popup box by typing in mydomain\username and password. The $_SERVER[remote_user] is then filled with the username.